# Are flash cookies the same as http cookies?

Tags: flash, cookies

Are flash cookies the same as http cookies?

Are they stored in text files?

Why do flash cookies have a higher storage capacity?

Is this a security risk?

Translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional difference is that the flash cookies are shared between all the browsers installed in the system, whereas the usual cookies are "local" to the browser. Again, if your browser has separate profiles, all the profiles are sharing the same set of Flash cookies.

Comment: Where then are they stored on my computer?  Is it not a security risk that all browsers  have access to a shared file?

Comment: @Billy: (1) location of the Flash cookies is system-specific. On my Windows PC, they are stored at %APPDATA%\Macromedia, but the location on Linux or Mac will surely be different. (2) Browsers have no access themselves, but the web pages can access the Flash cookies through Flash plugin.

Comment: is that in UNC Format so i could get there from Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Billy: yes, just paste the string into the address bar. Explorer is able to expand environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same, hence the different name.

Flash manages it's own cookies, very much separately from [browser/http cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

Your browser will not have direct access to [flash cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object).

If the browser does not have Flash installed, flash cookies can't be used, but http cookies can.

Comment: Yes when you do it in a condescending way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the biggest difference is in scale. A standard HTTP cookie can store 4kb of data. A flash cookie can store 100kb of data.

Additionally, they are well concealed in your system, finding them is a bit more complicated than with a normal HTTP cookie.

http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/04/flash-cookies-explained/

for more info^